# How to access a single value from dataframe using a tkinter entry as a row index

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am writing a code where there are two dataframes, which can be accessed by if else conditions. 'srno' will be the row index of the dataframe, and using it I want to access a single value from the dataframe 'var' (column is fixed).

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *

win=Tk()
win.geometry('300x300')

srno_lb=Label(win,text='Sr no.')
srno_lb.pack()
srno_et=Entry(win,width=15)
srno_et.pack()
srno=srno_et.get()

df1=pd.read_csv('<filepath of 1st csv file')
df2=pd.read_csv('<filepath of 2nd csv file')

# if condition which accesses df1
    var=df1.column_name[srno] 
        
# elif condition which accesses df2
    var=df2.column_name[srno]
    
#var is used later

win.mainloop()
```

When i run this i get an error in the line where 'var' is defined

```
    KeyError: ''
```

I also tried using df.at

```
var=df1.at[srno,'<column name>'] #or df2
```

but this gives the same error.

How to fix this? or any other method to do the required task?

Answer (score 0):

There's some good information [here](https://pythonhow.com/python-tutorial/pandas/Accessing-pandas-dataframe-columns-rows-and-cells/) regarding accessing specific parts of a given dataframe.

The examples there would seem to imply that `loc` is the method you want. You can do the following if you're trying to extract data from a single "cell":

```
var = df1.loc[srno, '<column name>']
```